# How to Create C++11 system_time from UTC Date (Thread-Safe)

Tags: c++, datetime, c++11, timezone

This can't be as difficult as the examples I found online.  I am attempting to create a `std::chrono::system_time` based on some UTC date.  The code that I have working in a single thread is the following:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int main() {
    // Construct a time to be Jan 1, 2020 00:00:00 UTC
    static tm someTime{
        0, // seconds after the minute - [0, 60] including leap second
        0, // minutes after the hour   - [0, 59]
        0, // hours since midnight     - [0, 23]
        1, // day of the month         - [1, 31]
        0, // months since January     - [0, 11]
      120  // years since 1900
    };
    setenv("TZ", "UTC", 1);
    tzset();
    auto const time = system_clock::from_time_t(mktime(&someTime));
    setenv("TZ", "America/Denver", 1);
    tzset();
    auto const t = system_clock::to_time_t(time);
    cout << ctime(&t) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I am printing in a different timezone to ensure the setenv is working.  Is there a thread-safe way to create a C++11 time from a UTC date?

Comment: I didn't understand your need, can you explain why "thread-safety"? which part of the code does not seem thread-safe for you? (concurrent calls of from_time_t, to_time_t, ...)

Comment: @Landstalker the setting of the global `TZ` is not thread-safe as some other thread may be depending on the old value of `TZ`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++20 (yes I know you don't have C++20, just stick with me) you'll be able to do this:

```
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;
system_clock::time_point someTime = sys_days{2020y/1/1};
```

You can use this syntax in C++11 by using [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, header-only library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date):

```
#include "date/date.h"

using namespace date;
using namespace std::chrono;
system_clock::time_point someTime = sys_days{2020_y/1/1};
```

The difference is that the new names are in `namespace date` instead of `namespace std::chrono`, and the UDL `y` is renamed to `_y`.

This is both efficient and thread-safe.  If you would rather code it yourself, [here are the algorithms this library uses](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html).

Comment: I've seen this answer posted on a number of questions.  At first I thought it was a shameless plug (since it is for your own library).  Having finally skimmed the code, I now see that you are just a philanthropist trying to inform the public about the availability of this great library.

Comment: I should also add that Howard is one of the co-authors of the proposal for [Extending <chrono> to Calendars and Time Zones](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0355r7.html), and his implementation is the proof-of-concept upon which the C++20 standard is based.

Comment: Any suggestions you have on how I might offer this preview of C++20 to C++11 (and up) clients without sounding like a shameless plug, are more than welcome.  I've been struggling with this issue too.

Comment: I recommend changing the text in between the code blocks to something like, "Until C++20 is standardized, you can use [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, header-only library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  This library is the implementation upon which the C++20 proposal is based, with a slightly different syntax due to lack of compiler support:".  For me, the fact that your library is the basis for the standard is a significant differentiator, as it indicates a level of quality and scrutiny that most third-party libraries don't provide.